# What collection do I use to write a Connection pool?

Tags: java, collections, connection, connection-pooling

Most of the code examples I found about connection pooling use a Vector for thread-safety, and to my understanding vector is old news. So my question is, what collection would be the most suitable for creating a connection pool?

Comment: Why are you coding this yourself? The collection depends heavily on the exact code you're writing. Probably something in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: Why not examine some of the many of the open-source Java connection pools already out there to get some ideas:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/, http://jolbox.com/, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/